# Desarrollo de plugin SEPE

Tags: php, soap, moodle

Estoy intentando desarrollar un plugin para el seguimiento de acciones formativas para moodle.

Por ahora he creado una base de datos e insertado manualmente los datos del centro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os pongo el código que llevo por ahora.

server.php

```
<?php

if(!extension_loaded('soap')) {
  dl('php_soap.dll');
}

require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/utilidades.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/clases/RespuestaObtenerDatosCentroSoap.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/controladores/CentroFormacionControlador.php';

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
$servidor = new SoapServer(
  URL_WSDL,
  ['encoding' => 'UTF8']
);

$peticion = file_get_contents('php://input');
$peticion = str_replace('mustUnderstand="1"', 'mustUnderstand="0"', $peticion);
$peticion = str_replace('xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"', '', $peticion);
$documento = new DOMDocument();
libxml_clear_errors();
$estado_previo = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$documento->loadXML(
  $peticion,
  LIBXML_NOWARNING
);
$path = new DOMXPath($documento);
$path->registerNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$cabecera = $path->query('//soap:Header/*');
$datos_cabecera = null;
$accion = null;
$usuario = null;
$clave = null;
if($cabecera->length > 0) {
  $datos_cabecera = headers2array($cabecera);
  if(isset($datos_cabecera['wsa:Action'])){
    $accion = $datos_cabecera['wsa:Action']['#text'];
  }
  if(isset($datos_cabecera['wsse:Security']['wsse:UsernameToken']['wsse:Username'])){
    $usuario = $datos_cabecera['wsse:Security']['wsse:UsernameToken']['wsse:Username']['#text'];
  }
  if(isset($datos_cabecera['wsse:Security']['wsse:UsernameToken']['wsse:Password'])){
    $clave = $datos_cabecera['wsse:Security']['wsse:UsernameToken']['wsse:Password']['#text'];
  }
}
$servidor->addFunction('obtenerDatosCentro');
$servidor->handle();

function obtenerDatosCentro() {
  global $usuario, $clave;
  $codigo = 0;
  $msg = 'Correcto';
  if(credenciales_validos($usuario, $clave) === false) {
    $codigo = -2;
    $msg = 'WS no disponible';
    return RespuestaObtenerDatosCentroSoap::enviar($codigo, $msg, []);
  }
  $cf_controlador = new CentroFormacionControlador();
  if($cf_controlador->getConexion() === false) {
    $codigo = -1;
    $msg = 'Error con el acceso a la base de datos';
    return RespuestaObtenerDatosCentroSoap::enviar($codigo, $msg, []);
  }
  $centro = $cf_controlador->obtener();
  if($centro === 'excepcion') {
    $codigo = -1;
    $msg = 'Error al obtener centro';
    return RespuestaObtenerDatosCentroSoap::enviar($codigo, $msg, []);
  }
  $datos = [];
  $datos['ID_CENTRO'] = new SoapVar(
    [
      'ORIGEN_CENTRO' => $centro ? $centro['origen_centro'] : '20',
      'CODIGO_CENTRO' => $centro ? $centro['codigo_centro'] : '99999999998',
    ],
    SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
  );
  $datos['NOMBRE_CENTRO'] = $centro ? $centro['nombre_centro'] : 'Centro de teleformación número 00000001';
  $datos['URL_PLATAFORMA'] = $centro ? $centro['url_plataforma'] : 'https://sede.sepe.gob.es/portalSede/flows/inicio';
  $datos['URL_SEGUIMIENTO'] = $centro ? $centro['url_seguimiento'] : 'http://10.25.10.88:9080/ProveedorCentroTFWS/services/ProveedorCentroEndPoint';
  $datos['TELEFONO'] = $centro ? $centro['telefono'] : '915859999';
  $datos['EMAIL'] = $centro ? $centro['email'] : 'bajel@sepe.es';
  return RespuestaObtenerDatosCentroSoap::enviar($codigo, $msg, $datos);
}
```

CentroFormacionControlador.php

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../config.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../clases/Conexion.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../utilidades.php';

class CentroFormacionControlador {
 
  private $conexion = null;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->conexion = Conexion::crear();
  }

  public function getConexion() {
    return $this->conexion;
  }

  public function obtener() {
    try {
      $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare(
        "SELECT
            *
          FROM sepe_centro_formacion"
      );
      $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $stmt->execute();
      $res = $stmt->fetch();
      return $res ? $res : false;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
      return 'excepcion';
    }
  }

}
```

RespuestaObtenerDatosCentroSoap.php

```
<?php

class RespuestaObtenerDatosCentroSoap {

  public static function enviar($codigo_retorno, $etiqueta_error, $datos) {
    $array_principal = [];
    $array_principal['CODIGO_RETORNO'] = $codigo_retorno;
    $array_principal['ETIQUETA_ERROR'] = $etiqueta_error;
    $array_principal['DATOS_IDENTIFICATIVOS'] = $datos;
    if(!empty($datos)) {
      $array_principal['DATOS_IDENTIFICATIVOS'] = new SoapVar(
        $datos,
        SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        'http://entsal.bean.domain.common.proveedorcentro.meyss.spee.es'
      );
    }
    $respuesta = [];
    $respuesta['RESPUESTA_DATOS_CENTRO'] = new SoapVar(
      $array_principal,
      SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      'http://salida.bean.domain.common.proveedorcentro.meyss.spee.es'
    );
    return $respuesta;
  }

}
```

utilidades.php

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';

function credenciales_validos($usuario, $clave) {
  if($usuario === USER_WS && $clave === PASSWORD_WS) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function headers2array($response) {
  $headers = array();
  foreach ($response as $node) {
    if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
      $headers[$node->nodeName] = headers2array($node->childNodes);
    } else {
      $headers[$node->nodeName] = $node->nodeValue;
    }
  }
  return $headers;
}
```

Cuando paso el validador y los archivos necesarios del SEPE descargados de aqui https://www.sepe.es/HomeSepe/Personas/formacion/centros-entidades-teleformacion.html, me da la siguiente salida.

```
Iniciando programa de ProveedorCentroTFValidador...
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
obtenerDatosCentro     -     password incorrecto 'EPESSEPECESEPE'     -     OK
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Header not understood
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.application.ws.impl.ProveedorCentroTFWSStub.obtenerDatosCentro(ProveedorCentroTFWSStub.java:145)
    at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.cliente.business.services.impl.ProveedorCentroSvcImpl.validarObtenerDatosCentro(ProveedorCentroSvcImpl.java:121)
    at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.cliente.business.services.impl.ProveedorCentroSvcImpl.validarObtenerDatosCentro(ProveedorCentroSvcImpl.java:109)
    at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.validador.ProveedorCentroTFValidador.validarObtenerDatosCentro(ProveedorCentroTFValidador.java:109)
    at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.validador.ProveedorCentroTFValidador.main(ProveedorCentroTFValidador.java:36)
obtenerDatosCentro     -     datos identificativos correctos     -      KO
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Header not understood
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.application.ws.impl.ProveedorCentroTFWSStub.crearCentro(ProveedorCentroTFWSStub.java:709)
    at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.cliente.business.services.impl.ProveedorCentroSvcImpl.validarCrearCentro(ProveedorCentroSvcImpl.java:83)
    at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.cliente.business.services.impl.ProveedorCentroSvcImpl.validarCrearCentro(ProveedorCentroSvcImpl.java:66)
    at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.validador.ProveedorCentroTFValidador.validarCrearCentro(ProveedorCentroTFValidador.java:103)
    at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.validador.ProveedorCentroTFValidador.main(ProveedorCentroTFValidador.java:37)
```

Cuando pruebo con SOAP UI, obtengo esto. Me devuelve los datos del centro de la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cabecera se la he puesto yo, aunque en el archivo de ejemplo de SOAP UI del SEPE, la cabecera viene asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También en el mismo archivo de prueba de SOAP UI del sepe, la respuesta sale asi. Con atributos y mas cosas que no aparecen en mi respuesta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Podeis ayudarme con esto? ¿Que hago mal?

Muchas gracias por vuestra atención.

Saludos!

Comment: has encontrado alguna solucion para este tema?